# How to find the range of data overlap in column's of csv file

Tags: csv, overlap

I have a csv file that each column has different number of data in it. How can I find the range in which all columns have data in them? (something like this image)

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glIq7.png)

---

**Edit by @Fravadona:** A CSV is a text file; given the provided image, the data in it should be something like this:

```
Index,A,B,C,D
0,,,,1
1,1,,,1
2,1,1,,1
3,1,1,1,1
4,1,1,1,1
5,1,1,1,1
6,1,1,1,1
7,1,1,1,
8,,1,,
9,,1,,
10,,1,,
```

In fact, there might be semi-colons instead of commas, each field might be surrounded by double-quotes, etc... Each one of those "details" are important when processing text.

Comment: You should create a sample CSV that illustrates what you mean by "_ each column has different number of data_" and add it to your question; example: ```col1,col2,col2``` ```"value,1",value2,value3``` ```"""value4""",,value5```, etc...

Comment: Hi! Acutally I did, but the table was not readable, so I delete it. Now, I add an image to show exatly what I mean. The index 3-6 should we output here, where all the columns have value, and there is an overlap. Thanks!